# Exact meaning of NFS errorcode -110

Tags: linux-kernel, rpc, nfs, rootfs

Hy community,

I want to boot the rootFS of my targetboard via NFS but the bootlog always prints the error "NFS: failed to create MNT RPC client, status=-110". Does anybody know what this code exactly means or where I can look it up?

I have already done:

- enabled everything related to NFS,Root-FS etc. in the kernel-config
- my firewall is inactive, iptables set to ACCEPT for Input,Output and  Forwarding
- exported the nfs-directory in etc/exports and saved it afterwards
- checked that service nfs-kernel-server is running
- checked that every folder in path/to/nfsroot has every right ( chmod 777)
- rpcinfo on host verifies running nfs
- versions on nfs-server and client are the same
- mounted nfs-directory on targetboard (=client)
- pinging the server to verify that ethernet-connection is up

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The NFS client here uses the standard return value mechanism within the kernel. That means that error values are returned as the negative of the appropriate `errno` value. In your case, that is 110, or `ETIMEDOUT`.

Now, as to why you're getting a timeout, I can't say. Getting an NFS root working can be challenging to troubleshoot. It seems likely that there is some problem with the kernel networking "autoconfiguration" process. You need to be sure that the correct network driver is getting loaded, the interface is getting an IP address configured, and so forth.

If you haven't already seen it: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-Root.html

Comment: Thank you for the Info concerning the negative error values and for the link. The IP-addresses and stuff should be fine, I checked it with the "rpcinfo"-command on the NFS-server and pinging is also working. I guess something in the barebox-configration and/or kernel-configuration is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `showmount -e` command and make sure your NFS directory is there.

When I set up NFS for my beaglebone, I had to make changes to `bootargs` using `setenv` in the u-boot prompt. More specifically this:

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyO0,115200n8 noinitrd ip=192.168.0.10:255.255.255.0 earlyprintk root=/dev/nfs. rw nfsroot=192.168.0.23:/home/gabe/Desktop/BBNFS2/rootfs rootfstype=ext4 rootwait'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your response.The showmount-command displayed on the NFS server "export list for Roland-Linux-OS:   /home/roland/CID_SW/fsroot"         I use barebox on the client and when I type "mount" the console prints " 192.168.3.10:/home/roland/CID_SW/fsroot on /mnt/nfs/ type nfs"    During booting the commandline says: " ... ip=192.168.3.11:192.168.3.10:255.255.255.0::eth0: root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.10:/home/roland/CID_SW/fsroot,vers=3,udp rw rootfstype=ubifs noinitrd rootwait ro fsck.repair=yes"      Sorry for the bad formatting but the shortcuts seem not to work with a german keyboard.